# store and retrieve matrices in memory using xptr

Tags: c++, r, matrix, reference, rcpp

I would like to be able to store a matrix created in R in memory and return the pointer. And then later use the pointer to fetch back the matrix from memory. I am running R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport" on Ubuntu 13.01 and Rcpp version "0.10.6". I have tried ...

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP writeMemObject(NumericMatrix mat)
{
  XPtr<NumericMatrix> ptr(&mat, true);
  return ptr;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix getMemObject(SEXP ptr)
{
  XPtr<NumericMatrix> out(ptr);
  return wrap(out);
}

# This returns a pointer
x <- writeMemObject(matrix(1.0))
```

But this fails and crashes R when I try again

```
getMemObject(x)
Error: not compatible with REALSXP
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but have you checked out the `bigmemory` package? It has a `big.matrix` object that does what you're describing.

Comment: And it uses XPtr -- see the useful writeup at the Rcpp Gallery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointer you feed to `XPtr` here is the address of a variable that is local to `writeMemObject`. Quite naturally you have undefined behavior.

Also, external pointers are typically used for things that are not R objects, and a `NumericMatrix` is an R object, so that looks wrong.

If however, for some reason you really want an external pointer to a `NumericMatrix` then you could do something like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP writeMemObject(NumericMatrix mat){
  XPtr<NumericMatrix> ptr( new NumericMatrix(mat), true);
  return ptr;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix getMemObject(SEXP ptr){
  XPtr<NumericMatrix> out(ptr);
  return *out ;
}
```

So the pointer created by `new` outlives the scope of the `writeMemObject` function.

Also, please see the changes in `getMemObject`, in your version you had:

```
XPtr<NumericMatrix> out(ptr);
return wrap(out);
```

You are not dereferencing the pointer, `wrap` would just be an identity and return the external pointer rather than the pointee I guess you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe it pretty much the use case for the [bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/package=bigmemory) package.   Michael Kane wrote a [nice Rcpp Gallery article](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-bigmemory-with-rcpp/) about its use with Rcpp which should address your questions.