# Finalize or destroy xptr matrix in memory in RCpp

Tags: c++, r, memory, matrix, rcpp

This is a follow up to a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154003/store-and-retreive-matrices-in-memory-using-xptr) on storing and retrieving matrices in memory using xptr - which was fantastically answered - thank you very much. Now that I can create and retrieve matrices in memory using xptr how do I properly finalize/destroy the object. Rcpp objects should be automatically garbage collected on deletion but when I create the pointer, if I delete it in R I have to run gc() twice to recover the memory e.g.

```
// This function wraps the matrix an returns a pointer
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP writeMemObject(NumericMatrix mat)
{
  XPtr<NumericMatrix> ptr(new NumericMatrix(mat), true);
  return ptr;
}
```

The function to retrieve the matrix (from previous answer)

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix getMemObject(SEXP ptr)
{
  XPtr<NumericMatrix> out(ptr);
  return *out;
}
```

Then in R

```
createMemMatrix <- function(dims){
  ptr <- writeMemObject(matrix(runif(prod(dims)), nc = dims[2]))
  return(ptr)
}

ptr <- createMemMatrix(c(1e4, 1e4))
#mat <- getMemObject(ptr) # this works but not run here
rm(ptr);
gc(); # nothing seems to happen in memory
gc(); # memory is freed (visible in system monitor)
```

The `bigmemory` R package was mentioned in the answer to the previous question and their objects are memory freed right away

```
# In R
require(bigmemory)
# be careful this is a large matrix
x1 <- big.matrix(ncol = 1e4, nrow = 1e4)
x1[,] <- runif(1e8)
rm(x1)
gc() # memory is freed right away (visible on system monitor)
```

I have tried a similar method used in the `bigmemory` package and I to register the pointer when I create it:

```
// C function for destroying the matrix behind the pointer
void destroyItem(SEXP ptr)
{
  NumericMatrix *pm=(NumericMatrix*)(R_ExternalPtrAddr(ptr));
  delete pm;
  R_ClearExternalPtr(ptr);
}

// This function wraps the matrix an returns a pointer
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP writeMemObject(NumericMatrix mat)
{
  XPtr<NumericMatrix> ptr(new NumericMatrix(mat), true);
  R_RegisterCFinalizerEx(ptr, (R_CFinalizer_t) destroyItem, (Rboolean) TRUE);
  return ptr;
}
```

But this does not make a difference. The `bigmemory` package is great but I think it is worth doing this using Rcpp objects because a wide range of objects can be stored in memory.

Comment: You say the original question was fantastically answered, yet you did not accept an answer. why ?

Comment: Please share the full R code you use. I believe the memory is not released because the matrix is otherwise protected.

Comment: @RomainFrancois - silly me I didn't realise you had to click the big tick to accept the answer - that was my first time actually asking a question on stack overflow. I have now posted the full C/R code. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R has a generational garbage collector, see for example [this section of R internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#The-write-barrier). So calling `gc()` might not trigger a full collection every time.

Also, please note that `XPtr` already registers a finalizer that calls `delete`, so you don't need to register the `destryItem` finalizer. You only need to register a finalizer to do something in addition to `delete`ing the pointer. Luckily you don't get a double delete thanks to your `R_ClearExternalPtr` but this is dangerous anyway.